# Can "below" stand alone, without a complement?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, complements

I know that "below" can be used without a complement in a "deictic" (for lack of a better word) context, as in, for instance, "I will explain this in further detail below", but what about situations like the following, where the intended meaning is 'below the text' – can "below" still stand alone?

> Put the text at the top of the page, and then add the picture below.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly correct that way.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a debate about whether **below** is functioning as an adverb or a preposition, but both **above** and **below** can be used on their own:

> Write your name at the top of the page and then answer the question below.

> Enter the required information above, then click the link below.

While less common, you do see above and below used as adjectives. For example:

> Click the below link.

> The above items have something in common.